# Migrating a windows service from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.0

Tags: .net-3.5, .net-4.0, windows-services, migration

I have a set of windows services that were installed using the `InstallUtil` utility from the .NET 3.5 version.

If I migrated the projects to 4.0, do I need to uninstall them and then reinstall them using the utility from the v4.0 directory for them to work?
Or is it enough to change the target version from the project properties, re-compile them, and copy them to the installed location?

*Note*: I'm using features from .NET 4.0 like dynamic types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assembly identification will still be the same, you should not need to uninstall and reinstall the service to get it working.

Obviously you will need to ensure that the .NET 4.0 runtime is on the server, but that should do it.  The service will need to be "stopped" when you go to update the exe.

Answer (score 0):

Registering a service really just adds a bunch of keys to the HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services node of the registry.  The most important one being the ImagePath key that points to your DLL.  You can replace the DLL as frequently as you want with any other valid windows service (a common way people compromise computers, btw).

As the other poster said, as long as the service is stopped and depdencies available, you do not need to re-register your service.